# Cannot create dropdown to select user roles with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

I'm developing the Admin Panel for my website, and one part of it is managing users. I'm using FOSUserBundle for those tasks.

I'm using custom template (AdminLTE) for forms, and I cannot add a dropdown to select roles for user when I add a new one.

In `UserType.php`

```
$builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'User Role',
    'choices' => $this->roleHelper->getRolesForForm()
));
```

In `WCB\SaleBundle\Helper\RoleHelper.php`

```
...
public function getRolesForForm()
{
    $roleList = self::flatArray($this->rolesHierarchy);
    $roles = array();

    foreach ($roleList as $roleId => $roleName) {
        if ($roleId == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
            $roles[$roleName] = 'Admin';
        }
        if ($roleId == 'ROLE_USER') {
            $roles[$roleName] = 'User';
        }
    }
    return $roles;
}
...
```

Above `getRolesForForm()` function will return this array, which is correct format for using with Symfony's `choice` field type:

```
Array
(
    [ROLE_ADMIN] => Admin
    [ROLE_USER] => User
)
```

And the form's not working anymore, with this exception:

`The value of type "array" cannot be converted to a valid array key.`

When I add `'multiple' = true` to form builder, it works, but it's not a dropdown. It's HTML select box which allow multiple selection.

```
$builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'User Role',
    'choices' => $this->roleHelper->getRolesForForm(),
    'multiple' => true
));
```

I think, for role selection, it should be a dropdown, not a multiple-selection box. How can I achieve this? Anything wrong with my code? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a multiple-selection box indeed. 
Take into account that a user can (and usually will) have several roles. In your case, a user who has ROLE_ADMIN also has ROLE_USER (ROLE_ADMIN "includes" ROLE_USER if you are using FOSUserBundle).

Comment: my choice was to use checkboxes with the 'expanded' => TRUE

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't it be a dropdown? Because if you select role ADMIN, you will have all lower roles, which are defined in role hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this may be the problem since I don't have your full code and I am not sure what `self::flatArray($this->rolesHierarchy)` is returning but please notice that you are using `$roleName`, not `$roleId` as your array key. If `$roleName` is not a string then you will get this problem.

Comment: Hi. `self::flatArray($this->rolesHierarchy);` returns  `array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE USER');`, which I need to add to another array `roles` to make their user-friendly name.

Comment: Ok, then it seems this is not the problem. Could you post the exact point (line of code and file) where this exception is raised? This may perhaps give a hint on what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue lately and this is my work around (I created DataTransformer):

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ... 
        $builder->get('roles')->addModelTransformer(new RolesTransformer());
    }
}
```

And DataTransformer class:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class RolesTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($roles)
    {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($role !== User::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
                return $role;
            }
        }

        return $roles[0];
    }

    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        return [
            $string, User::ROLE_DEFAULT
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The role attribute from UserModel of FOSUserBundle expected an array. If you use a select normal, they don't return an array.